# Cypress looping through input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cypress

I want make a test (cypress) to loop through the inputs and type values in each input field, but i got error. Can anyone help me in that?
**Oops, it looks like you are trying to call a child command before running a parent command.**

```
    <div class="content__form">
     <div class="formcolcontainer">
      <div class="formcol">
       <div class="formrow">
        <input type="text" id="fname" class="forminput">
        <label for="fname" class="formlabel"> FName</label>
       </div>
       <div class="formrow">
        <input type="text" id="lname" class="forminput"> 
        <label for="lname" class="formlabel"> LName </label>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

submitFormData(fname, lname){
        
        const inputFields = {
            Fname: fname,
            Lname: lname,
        }
        cy.get('.formrow')
          .find('input')
          .then(input =>{
              cy.wrap(input).each((field, value) =>{
                  cy.find(inputFields[`#${field}`]).type(inputFields[`${value}`])
              })
        })      
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work, directly use the `<label>` text to get your value to input

```js
//earlier
const fname = 'John'
const lname = 'Jones'

const inputFields = {
  Fname: fname,
  Lname: lname,
}

cy.get('.formrow')
  .find('input')
  .each(($input, index) => {
    cy.wrap($input).sibling('label').invoke('text').then(label => 
      const value = inputFields[label.trim()];
      cy.wrap($input).type(value);
    })
  })
```

Comment: What if i have some optional inputs?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, loop through `inputFields` instead of using `.each()`

```js
const inputFields = {
  fname: 'Tim',
  lname: 'Turner',
}

for (const key in inputFields) {
  const value = inputFields[key]
  cy.get(`.formrow input#${key}`)   // one input only, no need for .each()
    .type(value)
}

// Verify form fields
cy.get('.formrow input').eq(0).should('have.value', 'Tim')      // passes
cy.get('.formrow input').eq(1).should('have.value', 'Turner')   // passes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do something like this. You can create an array with first name and last name and directly use them in `type` using their index positions.

```js
let inputFields = ['fname', 'lname']

 cy.get('.formrow').find('input').each(($ele, index) => {
   cy.wrap($ele).type(inputFields[index])
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, using `inputFields` to drive the test

```js
const inputFields = {
  Fname: { id: 'fname', value: 'Fred' },
  Lname: { id: 'lname', value: 'Smith'},
}

cy.get('.formrow').each(($row, index) => {
  cy.wrap($row).find('label').then($label => 
    const inputSelector = `#${inputFields[label.text()].id}`;
    const value = inputFields[label.text()].value;
    cy.get(inputSelector).type(value);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means

```js
cy.find(inputFields[`#${field}`])
```

is incorrect because `.find()` can't be used as first command in the chain.

You would instead use

```js
cy.get(inputFields[`#${field}`])
```

Also the selector to get the id would be different

```js
cy.get(`#${inputFields[field]`)
```